# WPF/Telerik - Selecting row in radgridview only by GrdViewSelectColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I want to disable possibility of select row by click on the row in radgridview. I want to selected rows only by clicking on checkboxes in GrdViewSelectColumn. Is it possible?

```
<telerik:GridViewSelectColumn DisplayIndex="1">
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
            ...
        </Style>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellStyle>
 </telerik:GridViewSelectColumn>
```

It's declare of GridViewSelectColumn. It's Frozen column.

In RadGridView I have set SelectionMode="Extended". When I could't find any property to resolve my problem I tried use event RadGridView_SelectionChanged and manipulating it but I can't detect if I clicked on checkBox.

Comment: Is there anything you've done to attempt to achieve this yourself? If so, please supply that code and let us know what part of it you don't understand or isn't working.

Comment: I added more informations

Comment: You could try to use one of the edit events found [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-events-edit.html) and check the value of your column on a `CellEditEnded` event. The documentation on that page states that when that particular event is raised it contains the old value and the new value. That should allow you check whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Comment: The link I provided to the documentation was technically for the Silverlight controls. I'm not sure if these are identical without comparing them word for word, but in case the regular WPF controls differ slightly [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-events-edit.html) is the link to the same page for the WPF version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set property CanUserSelect of RadGridView to false and make your own checboxes in GridViewSelectColumn.CellEditTemplate.

More details you can find here:
[http://www.telerik.com/forums/use-gridviewselectcolumn-as-only-method-of-selection][1]